# Is it possible have speakers pluged in side speaker out?

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, motherboard

I own Asus maximus VI Formula and I want to have speakers and headphones pluged in to motherboard. I don't wanna them work at the same time I want a possibility how to switch between them. And I don't want use front panel (cause it's broken). Is it possible?

This is how outputs looks like and I want use the black or gray (side or rear output) [image: MB outputs]

Comment: The round connectors on the right look like 3.5mm jacks and they should include speaker output. Typically, the headphone jack contains an internal switch that disconnects the speakers when headphones are plugged in.

Comment: I've currently pluged speakers into the green jack and microphone into the pink jack. But I need plug in headphones. I don't know which jack use and how can I set it up or switch between it.

Comment: This doesn't exactly meet what you're looking for, but the solution I went with for this exact problem was to use a spliter, and then power off my speakers when I didn't need them.